# In defining a directional derivative it is written $ \nabla f \cdot v=v f $, how is it?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

while discussing 1-forms, it is given

> Our goal is to generalize the concept of the gradient of a function to functions on arbitrary manifolds. What we will do is to make up, for each smooth function $f$ on $M$, an object called $d f$ that is supposed to be like the usual gradient $\nabla f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Remember that the directional derivative of a function $f$ in the on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the direction $v$ is just the dot product of $\nabla f$ with $v$ :
> $$
> \nabla f \cdot v=v f \qquad ............... (1)
> $$
> In other words, the gradient of $f$ is a thing that keeps track of the directional derivatives of $f$ in all directions.

I didn't get how the equation (1) is arrived at. I assume $v$ is a vector and $vf$ is product of $v$ with the scalar $f$. Please pardon me if this is trivial.

Comment: The notation is confusing. It is usually written with brackets as $v(f)$.
Here $v(f)$ is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$, the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$.

Comment: The identity is $\nabla_x f \cdot v = \nabla_v \cdot f$.